# problem with GUI documentation programs

Tags: gui, documentation

The problem is within a program that their documentation is in a html file. Let's say Tex maker or wxMaxima. When I click the tag "Help" it show me the documentation through the browser, not in a small windows has it used to show. 
I have Microsoft Windows in the same hard disk (in another partition) and I do not experience the problem there.

I have ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: Why do you expect other behavior? It is not a problem at all, it is how applications were compiled and packaged. Having special html-viewer in any application would be bad design. For other applications `yelp` exists.

Comment: @N0rbert I expect other behavior because before it showed something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzHfu.png instead of open other program.

Comment: Program on the screenshot is a [CHM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) file viewer from Windows. It is installed system-wide. But CHM is not native format for GNU/Linux. Here we have ordinary HTML files, so it is absolutely expected that they are opened in some kind of web-browser.

Comment: I see. Well, there is no problem at all... but do you know if I can set to open the documentation files of software in the yelp program?